# Fetching ksession from kmodule.xml taking long time in Drools

Tags: drools

I'm new to Drools, so please let me know if whatever I'm doing is the right way. So this is what I'm trying to do. Based on some input parameter passed by the user, I need to run different rule files. This is my code to fetch the rule file and execute the rules:

```
kieService = KieServices.Factory.get();
kContainer = kieService.getKieClasspathContainer();
kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession(userInput);  // This is the string the user passes as a parameter
kSession.execute(myObject);
```

The kmodule.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="Kbase1" packages="com.mypackage1.rules">
        <ksession name="abc" type="stateless"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

So if the user input is "abc", then I fetch Kbase1. The problem is, fetching the proper ksession is taking a long time (about 1.3 seconds). Right now, I have only 1 kbase in my kmodule.xml. But this is going to grow considerably. And I assume it is going to take even longer if the xml file grows. Moreover, I'm going to be getting lot of user requests. So 1.3 seconds is not acceptable at all.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better way to execute different rules based on user input?

Comment: Have you profiled which of those steps is taking the time? Getting the container, getting the session or executing the session? Getting hold of a session should take very little time (milliseconds usually, possibly sub-ms).

Comment: @Steve getting the session takes up a bit more than a second. So most of the time taken is in this step: kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession(userInput);

Comment: What about subsequent requests? For me with one of my test knowledge bases, the first 'new session' takes ~1600ms, but every request after that takes between 1 and 2 ms.